# Can anonymous users post?

Tags: discussion, new-users, anonymous-users

I know this is the case on some sites, but is it on this one? Can anonymous users (users who do not have an account) post?

Comment: Post what? AFAIK you don't need to register to post answers. Only posting questions, and participating in meta need accounts.

Comment: @muru: Oh, well that's my answer then! Can you convert it into an answer please so I may accept it. :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14340/do-we-really-need-or-want-the-post-tag

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in fact they can. It is for this reason (among others) that AskUbuntu requires some reputation points to be able to do activities such as voting up posts etc.